# Stripe create multiple subscriptions with different intervals on a single authentication

Tags: php, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, payment

Working with PHP language and integrating Stripe on my website. There are two plans on my site.

1. 75$ - per year.
2. 6$ - per month (kinda add-on that allows you to have more functionality)

The algorithm is, if a user chooses the first plan, the logic is simple, create recurring payment for 1 subscription only (3DS/SCA is enabled and working). Things get complicated when they choose the second one where they need to pay 75$+6$ and they're subscribed to both plans. When a user tries to pay for the 2nd plan, they're subscribed to the 2nd plan and the 1st subscription payment remains incomplete. Here's the code, can anyone tell me what am I missing here?

```
$subscription_data = \Stripe\Subscription::create([
                    'customer'  => $customer->id,
                    "items" => [
                        [
                            "plan" => $plan->id,
                        ]
                    ],
                    'payment_behavior'  => 'default_incomplete', 
                    'payment_settings'  => ['save_default_payment_method' => 'on_subscription'],
                    'expand'            => ['latest_invoice.payment_intent', 'pending_setup_intent'],
                ]);
```

Comment: It will needs clarification to fully help you so I recommend starting a conversation with Stripe Support. But you should be able to create 2 separated Subscription, one for $75 annual an one for $6 monthly. Both will need the payment completed to be activated.

Comment: For Subscribing both you need to add in the items array so payment will be combined and as per subscription schedule it will charge

Comment: Agree with @orakaro that you need to create separate subscription

Comment: yes, but it'll require separate SCA authentication for each subscription and that's the issue! If there anyway in which we can complete both payment with 1 authentication only? @orakaro

Comment: You can use a SetupIntent to collect their Card first. It will complete SCA. After that you can use the collected PaymentMethod to create as many Subscription as you want.